# Error in crontab - bad minute

Tags: linux, cron

could anyone give me a clue what am I doing wrong in the crontab below?
I'm getting `bad minute` error...
Here the entries:

```
0,15,30,45 * * * * /usr/sbin/netdate -v time.server.com > /dev/null 2>&1
*/5 03-23 * * 1-5  /path/to/job1.pl >> /tmp/job1.log 2>&1
7 * * * 1-5  perl  /path/to/job2.pl >>/tmp/job2.log
```

Comment: What if you change at the very first line to `*/15` instead of `0,15,30,45`?

Answer (score 1):

crontab should tell you which line the error is on, so focus on that.

I suspect you have a line that's been split in two and "in reality" doesn't have a valid number at the start of the line.